How do i trouble shoot published applications not being available for installation?
This is my first time setting up applications for SharePoint on-prem, and I think I've done all the required steps.

Issued a certificate containing a wild card cert for the apps domain names
Configured the central DNS with a wild card domain for the apps domain names as a CNAME for my SharePoint site
Bound the new cert to the Web Application for my SharePoint site in IIS
Created the App Catalog Site Collection and Site
Defined the app domain name and prefix
Added Everyone to the App Catalog Visitors group
Configured App request (denied access to MS App Store)
Added a helloworld-webpart.sppkg app to the App Catalog
Performed an iisreset /restart on the WFE

But when I go to a site and try listing applications available From Your Organization, it states There is nothing here yet.
What should I do to make sure the app catalog is set up properly and is working?

Does the app in the app catalog show any errors? And is enabled? Is the app catalog on the same webapplication?

No, yes and yes.

There could be an issue in the app. Did you download it or created it yourself?

Ok, this is really stupid.
I did a Deploy from the App Catalog, of the app I got from our developers, which deploys it to all sites in the Farm.
Apparently, when an App has been deployed. It no longer shows when trying to use the Add an app (depending on the type ?) feature of a site.
In my case the App was a Modern Page Web part, so it will only show up in a list when I try to add Web Parts to a Modern Page.
(Our developers are new to writing SharePoint apps, so they couldn't help out.)
